# Testcafe doesn't wait text to be rendered

Tags: internationalization, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
  + expected - actual
  
  -sign.up 
  +Sign up now
```

Im having this issue while asserting a text. It works if I add a wait delay before. Even though Im using visibilityCheck:true on this selector, it won't wait.

Is there something I can do to avoid manually adding waits?

```
test("Loads the app in english by default", async (t) => {
  await t.wait(20000);
  const signupText = await signUpPage.signupLink.with({
    visibilityCheck: true,
  })();
  await t.expect(signupText.textContent).eql("Sign up now ");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [assertion timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402728/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/eql#optionstimeout):

```js
await t.expect(Selector('h1').innerText).eql('text', 'check element text', { timeout: timeoutValue });
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because the text is there, it just hasn't yet rendered into a translation.

Comment: With this timeout, assertion waits until an actual value becomes an expected value. It should work. Please share a full simple sample that I can reproduce locally without special effort.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/cdiq9

This is all you need, the endpoint is even public at https://dev.remo.co/

Comment: It happens because you get [`DOMNodeState`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402670/reference/test-api/domnodestate) when you execute Selector in the previous step. You need to send `Selector` to the assertion. When you pass `Selector` to the assertion, `Selector` is executed periodically until a timeout is expired or the assertion becomes `true`.

Comment: yep that worked. Bundling the Selector expression inside the expect, did wait for it to load the text correctly. Thanks.